# How to throw FileNotFoundException when using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class WordList {
    private static Random r = new Random();

    private static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    String filename = "Cities.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WordList wl = new WordList();
        buffR(wl.filename);
        System.out.println(words);
        System.out.println(getRandomWord());
    }

    public static ArrayList buffR(String filename) throws IOException {
        words.clear();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            words.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
        return words;
    }

    public static String getRandomWord() {
        WordList wl = new WordList();
        String randomWord;
        if (words.size() > 0) {
            int index = r.nextInt(words.size());
            randomWord = words.get(index);
        } else {
            randomWord = wl.filename + " is missing";
        }
        return randomWord;
    }
}
```

There is a java.io.FileNotFoundException (regarding my BufferedReader method) when I run this code(I intentionally put a no existing file). However, I already threw IOException in my method header. What should I do to not encounter this error again?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Adding a `throws` clause to a method declaration simply states that the method _might_ throw an exception. It certainly doesn't stop exceptions from being thrown.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is thrown by `new FileInputStream().` It has nothing to do with the `BufferedReader` whatsoever.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You _do not_ need to throw an exception, it is thrown for you by the API. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: To not get a file not found exception, don't reference a non-existent file.  `java.io.File.fileExists` can be used to check if the file is there.

Comment: @HotLicks But it still mightn't be there when you go to open it. Pre-testing like that is therefore a waste of time. It's just extra code, timing windows, and repeated file system operations.

Comment: @EJP - But it's the only way to avoid the exception, which was the OP's (presumed) desire.  Otherwise one must handle the exception, and I don't get the impression the OP is quite up to doing that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that adding a `throws` does it say that the method can throw an `Exception`, you want to be handling an `Exception` if it is thrown. To do this, you can wrap the code chunk is a try-catch block.  There is no way to stop an `Exception` from being thrown if it should be thrown, but the try-catch block will make it so that your program doesn't crash.  The [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) is quite helpful.

For this example, you would do something like this:

```
try 
{
  //This already throws FileNotFoundException
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
} 
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach? I changed a few things, but I've documented it below.

```
// static, pass in the initial words lits.
public static List<String> buffR(List<String> words,
    String filename) throws IOException {
  words.clear(); // If you want to reuse it.
  String line = null;
  BufferedReader br = null;
  File file = null; // A file to read.

  try {
    file = new File(filename); // Create a File object.
    if (! file.exists()) { // It's not there!
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find file: " + filename);
    }
    // Proceed as before...
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      words.add(line);
    }
  } finally {
    br.close(); // Let's try to not leak any resources.
  }
  return words;
}
```

Comment: What's the point when `BufferedReader` already throws a `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: @SteveP. Well, if you negated the logic you could avoid the exception. Also, I was just answering OP's question.